# Why do my jest tests run locally, but not on Travis?

Tags: javascript, import, travis-ci

I have a simple javascript project that is using ES6, plus `import` and `export`.  Here is my `.babelrc` file

```
{
  "env": {
    "es": {
      "presets": [
        [
          "env",
          {
            "targets": {
              "browsers": ["last 2 versions"],
              "node": "current"
            },
            "modules": false
          }
        ]
      ],
      "ignore": ["**/*.test.js", "**/tests/*"]
    },
    "test": {
      "presets": ["env"]
    },
    "cjs": {
      "presets": [
        [
          "env",
          {
            "targets": {
              "browsers": ["last 2 versions"],
              "node": "current"
            }
          }
        ]
      ],
      "ignore": ["**/*.test.js", "**/tests/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

I run my tests with `npm test`, which runs this command out of my `package.json`: `"test": "jest --notify"`.

Locally, everything runs fine and all my tests pass, but when I push to Travis, I get this error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`.  It does not recognize my `import` statements.

Here is my `.travis.yml`:

```
language: node_js
cache:
  yarn: true
node_js:
- '8.4'
script:
- npm test
env:
- NODE_ENV: feature/travis
```

Why is my `.babelrc` not working on Travis?  What am I missing?

Comment: Probably a dependency issue (such as a globally installation of a different version of jest) on your local machine, or neglecting specify a dependency and having bad state on either machine. Also, are you running node 8.4 locally as well?

Comment: node version is the same locally.  `jest` is not installed globally, so that is not the issue either.  What other dependencies would you look at?

Comment: Babel, but honestly, if you are sure neither environment has any global packages, there isn't much to go on. Log into your CI server and execute the code manually, check versions, etc. Barring that, add logging

Comment: I don't use global packages any more.  I have had too many bugs around them.  I will try logging now - if travis will let me.

Comment: Noted.  I will take another look.

Comment: Just ran a `npm ls -g --depth 0` and 3 packages did return.  Only `npm` is  being used in this project.  `/usr/local/lib
├── n@2.1.8
├── nodemon@1.14.3
└── npm@5.5.1`

Comment: Good. +1 for keeping things clean/knowing what you have. One thing you might look into is that, often, the NPM version itself may get out of sync between environments.

Comment: Doesn't the `ignore` key in the `.babelrc` above, tell `babel` to not process the files in those directories?

Comment: Yes, that is [the idea](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/5532). However, Node.js did not introduce support for running ES Modules natively until 8.9 (and it was and is still behind a flag) so that means that _something_ must be transpiling them. Also, it looks like you are using yarn, not npm so...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164450/discussion-between-jhamm-and-aluan-haddad).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely happening because you have defined `NODE_ENV: feature/travis` in your `travis.yml`. This will cause Travis to run your tests as `NODE_ENV=feature/travis jest --notify`.

This generally shouldn't cause concern, but `jest` will automatically set the NODE_ENV to `test` if it is not already set.

It could be that you're issue is similar to the discussion taking place over at https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3370. There is some contention on whether Jest *should* be automatically setting the `NODE_ENV` to `test` or if it should just use `development` if no `NODE_ENV` is present (or just respect whatever `NODE_ENV` is already set if its set globally).

You can also see this logic in the `jest-cli` https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/jest-cli/bin/jest.js#L12-L14

So my recommendation is to test this *without* having your `NODE_ENV` set in your `travis.yml` to see if it successfully runs all of your tests.